Slicing Animation in RealityKit/VisionOS
I have a model loaded in my view (a simple cube) and I want to slice it based on the user's drag gesture (ie. axis of slice animation should be co-axial to the drag gesture). It should slice the model, essentially splitting it into two.
I am unsure of how to animate this so that it's always based on user's mouse gestures instead of a pre-determined animation.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Until you have an ai that can decide how to split a model, and the changes to that model based on the data you have to create it. It should be several models or meshes.
